# Select COUNT distinct and round it up to the nearest hr

Tags: sql, visual-studio, charts, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to display a bar chart with the x-axis as a timestamp for the hr and the y-axis as the number of times the bus got flagged.
But for some reason the program is able to run on visual studio but there is no errors. I have done breakpoint and it shows that I am able to divide the timestamp properly in the hr group of 1200hrs, 1300hrs and 1400hrs. But other than that I believe there is a problem with the count.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBus" runat="server"  Width="200px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBus_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Bus Number</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="1">Bus 10</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="2">Bus 45</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="3">Bus 14</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>



string query = string.Format("SELECT DATEPART(HH, [datetime]), COUNT(busFlagDataID) FROM BusFlagData WHERE busStopID='52014' GROUP BY DATEPART(HH,[dateTime]) ORDER BY DATEPART(HH,[dateTime]) ", ddlBus.SelectedItem.Value);
DataTable dt = GetData(query);

        string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        decimal[] y = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
        }

        BarChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.BarChartSeries { Data = y });
        BarChart1.CategoriesAxis = string.Join(",", x);
        BarChart1.ChartTitle = string.Format("{0} Bus Flagged for", ddlBus.SelectedItem.Value);
```

This is my datatable

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BusFlagData] (
    [busFlagDataID] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [busStopID]     VARCHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
    [busID]         INT           NOT NULL,
    [dateTime]      DATETIME2 (0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([busFlagDataID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_BusFlagData_Bus] FOREIGN KEY ([busID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Bus] ([busID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_BusFlagData_BusStop] FOREIGN KEY ([busStopID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BusStop] ([busStopID])
);
```

Comment: Can you show us, perhaps by way of sample data, what might be wrong with the query?

Comment: Nothing is shown